# Load all templates from one file in angular js

Tags: angularjs

All, Forgive me it is not a solution-finding question. Before I posted this question. I already found a way to make it. Please see it from [vojtajina example](https://gist.github.com/vojtajina/3354046). Honestly it really ggod work for me .My problem is I can't understanding how and why it works well. So I tried to post some questions here to ask for some help. Please see my questions.

1. I found `angularjs` already have a service named `$templateCache`. But there also has a `factory` with the same name in the vojtajina's solution .IMO, I think the author want the `factory` overwrite the original `service`. So the service will not works in the vojtajina's solution, Is it right ?
2. The most hard part for me is return the object `{ status: response.status, data: cache.get(url)}` . What is this object used for?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the factory defined in the fakeTemplateCache.js will override the original definition, which only picks it up from $cacheFactory. The change in that example is so that the all-templates.html can be loaded and the actual template rendered during runtime. With this change , angular will not know anymore about the original definition of $templateCache.
2. The return value is what gets passed over to ngRoute for displaying the content. The "data" part of it is used for displaying the content and status is the HTTP status. This is pretty similar to how you would do a simple $http.get and get the status/data.

Comment: Thanks your explaining, Better to paste the related source code from angular to demonstrate what is angular doing for data :)